# Creating more than one new custom ('junction') object at a time

Tags: junction-object

I have a created a custom 'junction' object, which contains custom fields that lookup a Campaign and an Installation Address.

If possible, I would like to create more than a single instance of this object at a time, as the picture shows. I've created a new junction object from a Campaign in the picture.

I would like to be able to choose more than one installation address at a time, and then creating multiple, single records. Ie., one record = (campaign A, inst. addr. X), next record = (campaign A, instr. addr. Y), etc.

Creating one at a time is terribly inefficient. Is there any way I can add more than a single record at a time?

[image: Picture of modal where you can add a single new custom item]

Answer (score 2):

Using standard functionality via the UI this is not possible. You currently only have the "Save & New" Button.

One Option which could work: You can think of building a more efficient screen flow for the data entry, in which a user can select multiple Installation Addresses for one campaign. The flow will then create a record for each selected installation address.

Dependent on the amount of records you need to create you can also prepare a CSV and use tools like:

- Salesforce Dataloader
- Import Wizard
- Any other data loading tool which is out there on the market

If you need something more specific and more customized: The only other option would be to develop a Lightning Web Component, in which you can create multiple records at once (e.g. in some kind of table). The design and use cases this LWC should cover would then totally be up to you. But keep in mind, that for every change you would need a developer to include (e.g. a new Custom Field) into this LWC.